# Unable to understand the behaviour of pytest yield fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class ExternalRouter for which I need to write test cases.

external_router.py -

```python
class ExternalRouter:
    def __init__(creds):
        self.creds = creds
    
    def post_details():
        # logic...
```

and router factory to provide credentials to router class.

router_factory.

```python
class RouterFactory:
    @static_method
    def get_router():
        creds = fetch_from_aws_parameter_store()
        return ExternalRouter(creds)
```

here, I have test files to test the above code -

conftests.py -

```python
@pytest.fixture
def mock_creds():
    config = {"username": "bla", "password": "bla"}
    with mock_ssm():
        put_config(key, config)
        yield config
```

test_router_factory.py

```python
def test_router_factory(mock_creds):
    router = RouterFactory.get_router()
    # assert ...
```

I am using the yielded fixture in the router factory test but I have another test file that does not use the fixture but those test cases are also passing.

test_post_details.py

```python
def test_post_details():
    router = RouterFactory.get_router()
    router.post_details()
    # assertions
```

Ideally, these test cases should fail with AWS error. If I change the fixture from yield to return then all the test cases are failing as expected. I am unable to understand how the yield is affecting other test cases.

Comment: This is strange - for a function-scoped fixture the mock should be reverted after the test function. What you describe could happen for a module- or session-scoped fixture. I may be missing something here...

Comment: Ageeed. As far as I can tell, you’re thinking about fixture scoping correctly, but it’s going to be hard for us to actually debug this without a complete [mre]

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with scope. I have tried explicitly providing the scope in the fixture using `@pytest.fixture(scope='function')` but the behavior was the same as explained. As per docs, the default scope is function.

Comment: In this case I have to second @MichaelDelgado - without a reproducible example it is difficult to say anything (apart from "it should work").